# Change the last page before app goes to suspended state (WP8)

Tags: windows-phone-8, tombstoning

When the user presses and holds back button (or presses Win btn), then app is deactivated and app switcher is shown. The problem is that app's last page should not be visible in app switcher, because there is a sensitive data. 
How can I hide last page's content or navigate to other page before app goes to suspended state?